# How to activate a dropdown list when I click a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following radio buttons and a dropdown in my rails form. One radio button is for 'yes' and another for 'no'

```
<input type="radio" value="true" name="staff[optquestion]">
<input type="radio" value="false" name="staff[optquestion]">

<select class="form-control" name="staff[Redesignation]"><option value=""> 
</option>
```

I want when a user clicks on 'yes' the dropdown below gets selected.
Here is my javascript/jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[name=staff[optquestion]]").change(function(){
        $("[name=staff[[Redesignation]]").toggle($(" 
[name=staff[optquestion]]").index(this)===1);
    });
});
```

I have placed the script in application.js but nothing happens. When I place the script in staffs.coffee I get the error "reserved word 'function'"

I know I could me mixing js and jquery here but am only starting out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be careful while selecting elements by name in jQuery.
For handling radio button inputs you should use here in your case :

```
$("input:radio[name='staff[optquestion]']")
```

And also remember to enclose the inputs in a form for better control.
So,

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" value="true" name="staff[optquestion]" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" value="false" name="staff[optquestion]">
    <select class="form-control" name="staff[Redesignation]">
        <option value=""> 
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And the JS will be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[name='staff[optquestion]']").change(function(){
        $("[name='staff[Redesignation]']").toggle();
        });
});
```

Since there are only two radio buttons here in use, this will work. Incase you have more than 2 you must check with values of the radio buttons using **this** in the event handler.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much

Comment: Quick one: from that script, how would I change it so that when a user clicks 'yes' the drop-down disappears, but when the user clicks 'no' it now appears? basically the opposite @Boo

Comment: Like I said in the answer you can do a conditional to check the value of the radio button like 
`if ( $("input:radio[name='staff[optquestion]']").value === "false" ) 
$("[name='staff[Redesignation]']").show()
 else $("[name='staff[Redesignation]']").hide(); `
simple as that

Comment: That works. Thank you. Instead of the dropdown disappearing, can I just deactivate it @Boo?

Comment: Here : `$("[name='staff[Redesignation]']").attr("disabled", true)`

Comment: Thank you so much!